# How to round polynomial coefficients when using the polyfit() function?

Tags: python, numpy

I fit a polynomial to points from list `data` using the `polyfit()` function:

```
import numpy as np

data = [1,4,5,7,8,11,14,15,16,19]

x = np.arange(0,len(data))
y = np.array(data)
z = np.polyfit(x,y,2)

print (z)
print ("{0}x^2 + {1}x + {2}".format(*z))
```

Output:

```
[0.00378788  1.90530303  1.31818182]
0.003787878787878751x^2 + 1.9053030303030298x + 1.3181818181818175
```

How to get a fit to points, with rounded coefficients for example to three decimal places? For example, to get:

```
[0.004  1.905  1.318]
0.004x^2 + 1.905x + 1.318
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in the `polyfit` method for the purpose of rounding. IIUC, you can use `round` after applying `polyfit`.

```
import numpy as np

data = [1,4,5,7,8,11,14,15,16,19]

x = np.arange(0,len(data))
y = np.array(data)
z = np.polyfit(x,y,2).round(decimals=3)
array([0.004, 1.905, 1.318])
```

***For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value.*** **Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0**, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard [R9] and errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten. -- Cited from [`numpy.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html)

Comment: Thanks. And the above method rounds coefficients after finding a curve or while searching for a curve?

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski after fitting. `np.polyfit(x,y,2).round(decimals=3)` is equivalent to `np.round(np.polyfit(x,y,2), decimals=3)`